# External Connections to NIFI HTTPListen processor

Tags: apache-nifi, httplistener

I set up a httpListen processor to listen on port 8080.  It works just fine when I use postman connect to the local host on 8080 but externally the connection is refused.  I think it may be the nifi.properties file that has to be configured to all external connections.

From a endpoint on the same network as the nifi server, I was able to ping the NIFI server but running the command wget http://<private_NIFI_IP>:8080/contentListener the connection refused.

From the NIFI server I ran the same command and received a 405 error: Method Not Allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth reading the [documentation for ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/), as it's quite specific on what is and is not supported with this processor.

Specifically, see this section:

> Only HEAD and POST requests are supported. GET, PUT, and DELETE will
> result in an error and the HTTP response status code 405.

Which explains the 405 Method Not Allowed when you issue a GET from the local machine.

If you are wanting to create an externally accessible HTTP endpoint within a NiFi Flow, you should instead look at using [HandleHTTPRequest](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/). I also wrote a post that goes into more detail about creating REST APIs in NiFi [here](https://alasdairb.com/2021/08/09/building-a-simple-rest-api-in-nifi/).

Regarding external access, there are several things to check. First, configure your HandleHTTPRequest as you need it and start the processor (configure a Port that is different from your NiFi UI port).

On your NiFi host, run `ss -anp | grep <configured listen http port>'` and find the line that starts with `LISTEN` for the port you configured. Pay attention to the IP it is binding to - if it shows `127.0.0.1` then this will not be accessible from anywhere but the NiFi host itself. Ideally you should see here either the NiFi host's public IP, or 0.0.0.0, or *.

If you can see that, from another host, try `curl http://<nifi public ip>:<configured listen port>` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the NiFi GUI from another computer on the network?
I would guess not, and that NiFi has been configured to only listen on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) as newer versions are out-of-the-box.

Open nifi.properties and change the value of "nifi.web.https.host" From 127.0.0.1 to the IP address you want to use. Then restart NiFi. This will enable remote access to NiFi, so do use security!

If it already has a hostname there, check the resolved IP address by using nslookup. it may resolve to 127.0.0.1 due to a hosts file or other misconfiguration. You can enter the IP address instead, though for a production deployment you should really fix name resolution and use the hostname.